# Switch loops with SPDT switch

Tags: xbee, switch, drone

I have made a drone/car quadruped robot thing and I need help with the code. I have found two codes to use to control each aspect of it but I need help to connect them. I have made a radio controller with a Xbee 3 Pro that has a spdt (two position switch) and I want to use it to switch the modes. I want the car to be LOW and the drone to be HIGH (If it helps the switch is on pin digital pin 9 of a Arduino Nano). I am a beginner at the coding aspect of the project and I would appreciate all the help I can get.

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enT-O4NwCzc]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enT-O4NwCzc

Comment: please add your code to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a SPDT switch. A SPST works just as well.

If you have a SPDT switch with 3 positions (pole 1 closed, open, pole 2 closed) you can use it to activate one pin or the other, or neither.

Let's pretend your switch is an SPST. Ignore one of the poles (pole 2, say.)

Connect a digital pin to pole 1. connect the common (center) pin to ground.

Set your digital pin to `INPUT_PULLUP`. Now, when the pin is LOW, the switch is closed (mode A). When the pin is HIGH, the switch is open (mode B).

Comment: Thank you I just checked back in and this is very helpful. Do I need a resistor like as if it were a pushbutton

Comment: If you use `INPUT_PULLUP` mode then the Arduino connects the pin to +5V through an internal restistor, so you don't need an external resistor. That is true for pushbuttons as well. (However, when you use  `INPUT_PULLUP`, the pin reads HIGH when the switch is open, and goes LOW when the switch is closed.)